# How to implement change event in controller for lable with select html id in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to implement change event in controller for html id in sencha touch

```
{
            xtype:'label',
            id:'region',
            html:'<select **id="regionDropDown"** class="regionSelect"></select>',
            hidden:true

    },
```

I want to implement change event for id regionDropDown for  select  tag in html in sencha controller file can anybody tell how to do

Thanks

Comment: Means you want to fire event when html will be changed?

Comment: @MohitSaxena yes mohit when user change dropdown .I need to handle in controller

Comment: You can use updateData event for this.

Comment: You can add eventlisterner to the `regionDropDown` as simple javascript in controller's `init` event or view's `initialize` event, but note that `regionDropDown` is not sencha control so  you will not get any sencha touch control property. Instead you should use `selectfield` which will be more useful.